# How to use Angular UI Bootstrap Tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use Angular UI Bootstrap Tooltip `ui.bootstrap.tooltip` separated.

I'm able to use tooltip by adding full `ui-bootstrap` file, like:

```
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
<script>var App = angular.module("App", ['ui.bootstrap']);</script>
```

But **I want to include only tooltip functionality instead of adding full UI Bootstrap featured.**

Comment: ui.bootstrap is a module .. you need to add it as a dependency to use tooltip. You cant separate it

Comment: See the answer i have posted. Please take care of the "external resources" included in the JSfiddle. You need to include those in your project for making it to work.

Comment: I want to grab particular set of codes which has been used for tooltip instead of adding complete `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js`

Answer (score 2):

Use like this:

```
angular.module("App", ['ui.bootstrap.tooltip']);
```

it will load only tooltip library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this block of code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TooltipDemoCtrl">
  <div class="well">
    <div>Dynamic Tooltip Popup Text <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicTooltip"></div>
    <div>Dynamic Tooltip Placement <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicTooltipPlacement"></div>
    <p>
      Need some <a><span tooltip="{{dynamicTooltip}}" tooltip-placement={{dynamicTooltipPlacement}}>tips</span></a> ?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var TooltipDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {

  $scope.dynamicTooltip = "Here is the help";
  $scope.dynamicTooltipText = "tips";

};
```

Here is the working link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/40rusk4j/) to see it working.